# Calculate distance in 45 deg rotated rectangle

Tags: math, area

I believe this is a simple question.

Given I have a rectangle rotated 45 deg, what would be the correct method to calculate the distance of the blue line shown in the image?

It doesn't need to be language specific. Just interested to know in what is the arithmetic I should follow.

[image: calculate distance in rotated rectangle]

Comment: This is a math question, not programming. But the answer is 600/sqrt(2), which is a little more than 424 pixels. You can see that formula by remembering that a 45°-45°-90° triangle has sides 1-1-sqrt(2).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about math and not programming

Answer (score 2):

If your rectangle is rotated 45 degrees, then your distance is simply 1/sqrt(2) times 600px.

This is given by

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

Where a = b and is your blue line. C is simply 600 px. Simple algebra yealds:

```
2a^2 = c^2
sqrt(2)*a = c
a = c * 1/sqrt(2)
```

On the other side it would be 350 times 1/sqrt(2). Note this only applies to a rectangle rotated 45 degrees.

Comment: Correct but `600`, not `650` :)

Comment: Corrected 650 to 600.